# Is believing in G-d guided evolution a valid belief in Orthodox Judaism?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, parashat-bereishit, creation

Like the title dictates. Does the [theory of evolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwinism) hold legitamacy in light of Maaseh Bereishis? That being said, are there ramifications of having that understanding towards one's Avodas HaShem? If so why or why not?

Comment: once you accept God was involved how can you believe anything without having been there to witness it

Comment: [Breishis - Creationism and Evolutionism](http://sabbahillel.blogspot.com/2011/10/breishis-creationism-and-evolutionism.html) I point out that logically there is no difference at what point Hashem created the Universe. If evolution is a valid theory, then it would start from that point on. It is like drawing part of a curve in which the equation has a discontinuity before the part that was drawn and then getting into an argument about whether the discontinuty "exists"